# Spring 3 Dependency Injection and interfaces

Tags: java, spring, configuration, dependency-injection

here is some code from a post here that would explain my question:

Interface:

```
package org.better.place

public interface SuperDuperInterface{
    public void saveWorld();
}
```

Implementation:

```
package org.better.place

import org.springframework.stereotype

public class SuperDuperClass implements SuperDuperInterface{
     public void saveWorld(){
          System.out.println("Done");
     }
}
```

Client:

```
package org.better.place

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire;

public class SuperDuperService{

       private SuperDuperInterface superDuper;

       public void doIt(){
           superDuper.saveWorld();
       }

       public void setSuperDuper(SuperDuperInterface superDuper) {
         this.superDuper = superDuper;
       }
}
```

My question is - how can I configure the beans in the spring config? I don't want to use `@Autowired` and other annotations.

I guess it will be something like this:

```
<bean id="superService" class="org.better.place.SuperDuperService">
  <property name="superDuper" ref="superWorker"
</bean>

<bean id="superWorker" class=?????? parent=???????? >
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to instantiate the implementing class, of course:

```
<bean id="superWorker" class="org.better.place.SuperDuperClass"/>
```

You would only need the `parent` attribute if you wanted to create multiple beans with common properties that you don't want to repeatedly declare, so you move it to an abstract parent bean definition that the concrete bean definitions can reference.
Assuming the `SuperDuperClass` has some properties:

```
<bean id="superWorkerPrototype" abstract="true" 
      class="org.better.place.SuperDuperClass">
    <property name="prop1" value="value1"/>
    <property name="prop2" value="value2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="superWorker1" parent="superWorkerPrototype"
      class="org.better.place.SuperDuperClass">
    <property name="prop3" value="foo"/>
</bean>

<bean id="superWorker2" parent="superWorkerPrototype"
      class="org.better.place.SuperDuperClass">
    <property name="prop3" value="bar"/>
</bean>
```

Which would result in both instances having the same values for `prop1` and `prop2`, but different ones for `prop3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just give the implementation class's fully qualified name, and its not required to give `parent` attribute. Spring will automatically find if it can assign an instance of `SuperDuperClass` to the `superDuper` field of `SuperDuperService`

```
<bean id="superWorker" class="org.better.place.SuperDuperClass" >
</bean>
```

Comment: I don't see what would make Spring automatically inject a `SuperDuperClass` instance to the `SuperDuperService` without using `@Autowired` in it (which the OP wants to avoid).

Comment: unless you explicitly say @Autowired or mention auto-wire in xml spring doesn't auto-wire. What I tried to explain here is to avoid the parent tag cause spring will find out whether it can assign the instance or not

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean. Neither of them is in the code snippet in the question, so don't understand why you wrote that "Spring will automatically find if it can assign an instance of SuperDuperClass to the superDuper field of SuperDuperService"